# Java - second last occurrence of char in string

Tags: java, string

Suppose I've the string

```
String path = "the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/lazy/dog/";
```

I would like the following output

```
String output = "the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/lazy/";
```

I was thinking the following would do

```
output = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/", 1));
```

given how the doc says

> Returns the index of the first (last) occurrence of the specified character, searching forward (backward) from the specified index.

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? We need more info.

Comment: It seems to scan from the beginning, not the end. So the output comes just `/`.

Comment: As its stated in the docs. The method only return the index value and not a string

Comment: ^ That was a typo

Comment: Remember that with the `substring(start , end)`  makes a substring from the `start` to, but not including' the `end` index. So if you want the last `/` in your output string, just add +1 to your `end`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, given `path` length >2

```
final String path = "the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/lazy/dog/";
final int secondLast = path.length()-2;
final String output = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/",secondLast)+1);
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems like every single answer is assuming that you already know the input string and the exact position of the last occurrence of `"/"` in it, when that is usually not the case...
Here's a more **general method to obtain the nth-last** (second-last, third-last, etc.) occurrence of a character inside a string:

```
static int nthLastIndexOf(int nth, String ch, String string) {
    if (nth <= 0) return string.length();
    return nthLastIndexOf(--nth, ch, string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf(ch)));
}
```

Usage:

```
    String s = "the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/lazy/dog/";
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, nthLastIndexOf(2, "/", s)+1)); // substring up to 2nd last included
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, nthLastIndexOf(3, "/", s)+1)); // up to 3rd last inc.
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, nthLastIndexOf(7, "/", s)+1)); // 7th last inc.
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, nthLastIndexOf(2, "/", s))); // 2nd last, char itself excluded
```

Output:

> the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/lazy/
>   the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/
>   the/quick/brown/
>   the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/lazy

Comment: Definitely will be saving this. Very flexible.

Answer (score 3):

The [lastIndexOf](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-lastindexof-method-example/) method's second parameter specifies the maximum index upto where the method should search the string. This means, that in your case

```
path.lastIndexOf("/", 1)
```

returns the first index of "/" whose index is smaller than 1.

Comment: Yep got the problem now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `lastIndexOf` will return an index, not a string. It also searches *backwards* from the specified index `1`, so it will only look at everything *before* and including the character at index 1. This means that it only checks `t` and `h`. Expectedly, it finds nothing and returns -1.

You should just omit the second argument if you want to search the whole string.

In addition, to achieve your desired output string (I assume you want the last path component removed?), you can use `replaceAll` with a regex:

```
String output = path.replaceAll("[^/]+/$", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think you're right - regex is the best way to handle this. BTW, I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 2):

Try `- 1` approach:

```
int j = path.lastIndexOf("/");
int i = path.lastIndexOf("/", j - 1);      // the 2nd last index from the last index

String output = path.substring(0, i + 1);  // inclusive
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Apache Commons IO**

```
String output = org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getPath(path);
```

---

**Not using Apache**

```
public static String removeLastPart(String str) {
    int pos = str.length() - 1;

    while (str.charAt(pos) != '/' || pos + 1 == str.length()) {
        pos--;
    }

    return str.substring(0, pos + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with paths and files why not use the built in classes? Something like below seems to me easier than string manipulation:

```
Path path = Paths.get("the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/lazy/dog/");
System.out.println(path.getParent());
// prints: the\quick\brown\fox\jumped\over\the\lazy
System.out.println(path.getParent().getParent());
// prints: the\quick\brown\fox\jumped\over\the
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, 
String key = "aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd" ;

and i need my result string as "ccc/ddd". which is, sub-string of second last index of "/", The following code helps ::

```
    String key="aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd";
    key=key.substring(key.substring(0, key.lastIndexOf("/")).lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

The final value of key will be "ccc/ddd".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an use case:

```java
        String url = "http://localhost:4000/app/getPTVars";
        int secondLastIndexOf = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')).lastIndexOf('/');
        System.out.println(secondLastIndexOf);
        System.out.println(url.substring(secondLastIndexOf, url.length()));
```

and the output:

```sh
21
/app/getPTVars
```

Answer (score 0):

String path = "the/quick/brown/fox/jumped/over/the/lazy/dog/";

String output = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/",path.lastIndexOf("/")-1)+1);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).